# CSS calc doesn't work on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: c#, jquery, css

I have div which have id name is #monthlyconfirm_grid.
I used that Jquery process to control scroll from gridview
but it works only on IE and doesn't work on Chrome and firefox.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var expi = $("#monthlyconfirm_grid").scrollLeft - 2;
            var expr = "calc("+ expi +")";
            $(".locked").css("left", expr);
```

});

P.S: I used `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />`  to work on IE.

Why doesn't work on chrome and Firefox?
How can I solve that?

Comment: no...no warnings and errors for this.

Comment: Adding a function to a number? Interesting

Comment: I think Jquery file cannot access from chrome because when i accessed from IE, it was display message like "Jquery readed" and when i accessed from chrome, it didn't display any message

Answer (score 3):

[scrollLeft](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) is a function so you need to use parenthesis also:

```
var expi = $("#monthlyconfirm_grid").scrollLeft() - 2;
```

Comment: thanks!...but it still doesn't work on Chrome and firefox

Comment: no...cause of Information Security on Company rule, I cannot made test page

Comment: Please try to console.log(expi) and see the value. Are you sure you need calc()?

Comment: Yes, I used css expression before and I found that expression didn't support anymore on chrome and firefox. Therefore, I changed to use calc() and it is work on IE but It is doesn't work on chrome and firefox too. But I think there is no announcement about support or not on them.

Comment: Have you tried the following?
$(".locked").css("left", expi + 'px');

Comment: I tried but it is not work...I think Jquery file cannot access from chrome because when i accessed from IE, it was display message like "Jquery readed" and when i accessed from chrome, it didn't display any message

Comment: Checked, there is no problem with Jquery file ...why calc() didin't work?